# Fix indentation in align* environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

The first two lines have fewer characters than the second two in the the `align*` environment, they are flushed right and seem awkwardly out of alignment with the last two equations. (Note that the only reason I have an additional space in front within the text command in the last two equations like `\text{ if...}` and not `\text{if...}` like the first two is just from a (failed) attempt at fixing the spacing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots-\frac{1}{x^2+1} & \text{if $n$ is odd and is } 1,5,9,13,\ldots\\
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots+\frac{1}{x^2+1} & \text{if $n$ is odd and is } 3,7,11,15,\ldots\\
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots-\frac{x}{x^2+1} & \text{ if $n$ is even and is } 2,6,10,14,\ldots\\
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots+\frac{x}{x^2+1} & \text{ if $n$ is even and is } 4,8,12,16,\ldots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which outputs:

[image: long division]

I have ways to sooth this (like just saying n=4k+1, 4k+2, etc. or just specifying the conditions elsewhere before or after the equations), but for future reference, what would be a nice way to fix this inside of the `align*` environment? I think it would just look better if things were aligned to the left in the second part of the lines. Is there any best practice for something like this?

Also, I am aware of the `cases` and `dcases` environments and whatnot (which is what I finally used), but am seeking answers for this environment specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align` (and its starred version `align*` aligns content using a `R`ight `&` `L`eft approach around the alignment character `&`. Multiple alignments follow the same approach, separated by a single `&`. The following minimal example highlights this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  R1 & L1 & R2 & L2 & R3 & L3 & R4 & L4 \\
   R1&L1  &  R2&L2  &  R3&L3  &  R4&L4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The first line shows a bunch of `R`ight and `L`eft alignments, separated by alignment markers `&`. The second line has the pseudocode mimicing the alignment, for clarity.

With the above information, you want the left construction around the `=` to be aligned like `R1&L1`, while you want the textual description to be aligned to the `L`eft only (without a `R`ight counterpart) and therefore would use `&&L2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  % Alignment: R1&L1 & &L2
  \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\dots-\frac{1}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is odd and is $1,5,9,13,\dots$} \\
  \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\dots+\frac{1}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is odd and is $3,7,11,15,\dots$} \\
  \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\dots-\frac{x}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is even and is $2,6,10,14,\dots$} \\
  \frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\dots+\frac{x}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is even and is $4,8,12,16,\dots$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\dots`, which automatically switches to `\cdots` within a binary operator sequence, and `\ldots` within a series.

Answer (score 2):

Environment `align*` is intended for equation systems with right and left aligned parts. The example is fixed by using `&&` instead of `&` to get `\text{if...}` left aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots-\frac{1}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is odd and is } 1,5,9,13,\ldots\\
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots+\frac{1}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is odd and is } 3,7,11,15,\ldots\\
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots-\frac{x}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is even and is } 2,6,10,14,\ldots\\
\frac{x^{n+1}}{x^2+1} &= x^{n-1}-x^{n-3}+x^{n-5}-\ldots+\frac{x}{x^2+1} && \text{if $n$ is even and is } 4,8,12,16,\ldots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thank you for this and the helpful edits. Know where I can find some documentation that says this somewhere?

Comment: @anonymaker000010001 [User's Guide for the `amsmath` Package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf)